# When should I open/close the windows/curtains to keep the room cool in summer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, sun, air

Folk wisdom has it that in order to keep your room cool, it's best to close the window. I assume the reasoning is that while a breeze of air feels cool, in most traditional houses the outside air temperature is actually warmer, heating up the room.

However, I live in a studio directly under the roof with giant east-facing windows. In summer inside temperature can be easily 5 degrees Celsius *warmer* than outside. Yet friends keep advising me to keep my windows closed.

What is the correct approach?

What I have been doing is opening the windows as soon as outside temperature is cooler than inside temperature (estimated based on weather forecast and room thermostat) and keeping the curtains closed until the window is in the shadow. (related: [In summer, should I close curtains during the day?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/340227/))